# Facebook like button appear in random way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-like

I added XFBML facebook like button plugin on my site for activity entities, but button shows only for one of them in random order. Code looks like:

```
<body>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
...
<fb:like href="<%=activiy1_url%>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false" font="verdana"></fb:like>
...
<fb:like href="<%=activiy2_url%>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false" font="verdana"></fb:like>
...
<fb:like href="<%=activiy3_url%>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false" font="verdana"></fb:like>
...
</body>
```

Open Graph tags are present on the page. The same problem for iFrame button. What can be the reason ?

Comment: Have you checked your URL with the debug tool yet? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I've just checked it and found troubles with meta properties. Now it's working, thank you.